# ManyToOne Relationship not working in Symfony using Annotations Mapping

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to create a one to many relationship in symfony using annotations mapping. Everything seems fine but the constraint is not working. I can be able to insert data on the product table without inserting data on the supplier's table as the supplier is a super entity.
This is my attempt:

**Product.php**

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Supplier", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="$supplierId", referencedColumnName="$id")
     */
    private $supplier;
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="supplier_id", type="integer")
     */
    private $supplierId;
```

**supplier.php**

```
/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="$supplier")
     */
    private $products;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

After adding the above, I ran this command

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

But the relationship is never created, please what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you use php variable in name and mappedBy remove `$` sign from

```
@ORM\JoinColumn(name="$supplierId", referencedColumnName="$id")
```

and

```
@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="$supplier")
```

It should be

**Product.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Supplier", inversedBy="products")
 */
private $supplier;
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="supplier_id", type="integer")
 */
private $supplierId;
```

**Supplier.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="supplier")
 */
private $products;
```

More info you will find [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional)

Also if you want to avoid problems assign array collection to products variable.

Comment: After the modification in your answer above, when I run this command php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force

Comment: The coonsole tells me nothing to update. Everything already in sync

Comment: Maybe it's because you have already these tables in your schema? It will run update only if schema changed.